# WindowsのインストールされたHDDを別のPCに接続して起動したい

Tags: windows-10

Windowsの入ったHDDをノートパソコンから取り外してデスクトップに接続しました。
その際、デスクトップに接続されていたHDDは全て取外してあります。
その後UEFIで起動ドライブを設定し起動を試みましたが、Windowsは起動しませんでした。

HDDを移行するだけで起動したい場合はどういったことをすれば起動出来るようになりますか？
「Windowsの修復」もできませんでしたので、大人しくノートパソコンにつけ直しました。

Comment: 原因はエラー内容によると思います。あと「移行」ですよね？

Comment: おそらく、Q&Aサイト記事程度で出来ることでは無いと思われます。パソコンの組み立てとか詳しいショップへの持ち込みor出張サービス等を利用した方が良いでしょう。例えばこんな記事 [TPMとかbitlockerとか](http://pasoco.blog.jp/archives/1019782538.html) に係わる情報の確認をいちいち質問とコメントではやっていられないですよね。

Comment: 例えばBitLockerであれば回復キーの入力が求められるなど、何らかのメッセージが表示されるわけで、やはりその内容が解決の手がかりとなります。逆に言えばそれが質問者さんから提示されない限りは解決しないでしょう。

Comment: @sayuri 以降したかったのですがだめでした

Comment: @kunif HDDのロックなどはかけてはいないので中身は問題なく見れるので行けんじゃね？って感じで試してみましたがエラーだらけになりました

Comment: @su3158 さん、まあ紹介記事は例なので、起こり得る要因は他にも山のようにあるでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原則「できない＝不可能」と考えてください。技術的にダメかつライセンス的にダメの両面があります。

Windows PC は「デバイスドライバ」よりソフトウエア的に上位層（＝よりユーザーに近い層）はほぼ互換なのですが、デバイスドライバおよび、それよりハードウエアに近い層はそのハードウエア専用に作られています。通常運用されている Windows には、すべてのハードウエア用デバイスドライバはインストールされていないので、違うハードウエアデバイスを搭載している機械に差し替えると起動することは期待できません。

また OEM 版 Windows はライセンスが「その機械」に
同様 DSP 版 Windows はライセンスが「その部品」に
束縛されているので、違う機械にて使うことはライセンス違反です。
メーカー製ノートパソコンにプリインストール済み Windows は OEM 版のはずなので、他パソコンで使うことはライセンス違反になります。

パッケージ版 Windows はライセンスを異なる機械に移動させることはできますが、移動させると元の機械上でのライセンスは無効になりますので、移動させるたびに再認証が必要です。多頻度のライセンス移動認証を行うのはいろいろ厄介だったはず。

Comment: そう言った仕様になっていたのですか...知らなかった

Comment: 一概にライセンス違反とは言えません。ボリュームライセンス契約していれば移動可能でしょうし、そうでなくても[Windows 10の場合ストアから再購入を求める](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change#section-3)動きになっているようです。それよりもstack overflowは技術的な話題を扱うサイトですから、エラーの原因を究明する方が建設的に思います。